# log4j logger locale problem

Tags: log4j, locale

I am using Log4j Logger for my application.My application is supporting japanese language also,In japanese locale it is printing log date time in japanese but I want it should print in english only for debuging purpose because I dont know japanese.
plese help me how can I set locale english for logger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems log4j is using default locale, in your case Japanese. What you could try, is editing your `log4j.properties/log4j.xml`, make sure you use `PatternLayout` in each appender and configure it with ISO8601 date format (locale-independent), for example like so:

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %m%n"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: @NileshShukla Have you had a chance to test it? I'd like to know if it helped.